# How can I check if that item is on the arrayList?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I have an arrayList, and i want to know if the new added item is already on the list.

```
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result1) {
            //TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result1);
            progressBar.dismiss();

            if(status == 1) {   
                //arrayListItemEntries.add(itemEntryAdded);
                System.out.println(itemEntryAdded);
                System.out.println(arrayListItemEntries.get(arrayListItemEntries.size()-1));
                arrayListNewItems.add(itemEntryAdded);
                adapterItem.notifyDataSetChanged();
                toastMsg = "Item " + description +" is added on the list";                  
            }
            else
            {
                toastMsg ="Item not Found";
            }
            makeToast(toastMsg);
        }

    }
```

on the line,

```
 System.out.println(arrayListItemEntries.get(arrayListItemEntries.size()-1));
```

it outputs null, why is it? when i want to output the list size, its correct.

Comment: If you don't want duplicates in your list maybe you can change it to a `Set`.

Comment: The question in the title is how to check if an item is in the ArrayList.  the question in the question is "why is the last item in the ArrayList null?".  Which question should we pay attention to?

Comment: every item on the list is null but the size is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:-

```
if(arrayListItemEntries.contains(itemEntryAdded))
        // do nothing - already there in list
else
        arrayListItemEntries.add(itemEntryAdded);
```

Comment: if(arrayListItemEntries.contains(itemEntryAdded)) 

this output always false. and i dont know why.

Comment: that means, all the `itemEntryAdded` are new, and not already present in the `arrayListItemEntries`

Comment: but, the size of the arraylist is correct but all the items on the arraylist is null.

Comment: then probably, the `itemEntryAdded` which you are adding to your `arrayListItemEntries` are `null`. Hence, everything is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the  `contains(item)` method.

Answer (score 0):

What is your list size? Where are you adding items to this list?

usually we use `.contains(Object)` method to check for a particular object's existence.

You could also try using `Set` which doesn't allow duplicates, hence you do not need to check.